# How to set the path in form.php for admin configuration to view the image

Tags: module, admin, magento-1, configuration

I am uploading images in my module using the folowing code at:

\Block\Adminhtml\Visualcolor\Edit\Tab\Form.php

```
$fieldset->addField('image', 'image', array(
  label' => Mage::helper('visualcolor')->__('Image'),
  'required' => false,
  'name' => 'image',
 ));
```

then I save it fine at the controller into my specific folder at media and works fine.

```
$path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . "visualcolors" . DS;
$uploader->save($path, $_FILES['image']['name']);
```

The problem it is how do i get the correct path in the form.php instead the default "media" folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a custom form element for the image field.
So create this file:  `app/code/local/[Namespace]/[Module]/Block/Adminhtml/Visualcolor/Helper/Image.php`

```
class [Namespace]_[Module]_Block_Adminhtml_Visualcolor_Helper_Image
    extends Varien_Data_Form_Element_Image {
    protected function _getUrl(){
        $url = false;
        if ($this->getValue()) {
            $url = Mage::getBaseUrl('media').'visualcolors/'.$this->getValue();
        }
        return $url;
    }
}
```

now in your `Block\Adminhtml\Visualcolor\Edit\Tab\Form.php` file tell magento to use your block as the renderer for image fields.

Add this line of code right below `$fieldset = $form->addFieldset(....);`

```
$fieldset->addType('image', '[Namespace]_[Module]_Block_Adminhtml_Visualcolor_Helper_Image');
```

Comment: Thanks Marius works perfect I had it for the grid but not for the form...